# Controlling root certificates in the CA trust store

Tags: ios, security, truststore

Is it possible to programmatically perform CRUD operations on the trust store in iOS? I don't see anything resembling this in the [Certificates, Keys, and Trust Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services?language=objc) docs. In the iOS Settings it's only possible to see Trust Store Version with no details. Do users have any control over the contents of the trust store?

Comment: I would be _very_ concerned if any old app could just go mess with my CAs and trust settings.

Comment: Who said anything about "any old app"? I'm _very_ concerned that I have no ability, even manually in the iOS settings, to control which CAs are trusted. This is possible in every other OS that I'm aware of, including OSX. I didn't suggest that it should be easy or common or usual. I'm asking if it is _possible_.

Comment: Are you talking about personally manipulating the store on your own phone, rather than a programmatic API? That would probably be better on [SU] or [apple.se].

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to do so programmatically, using Swift, on iOS. I merely note that it is not possible in iOS settings, which makes me doubt that it is possible through an app.

Comment: If you can do it via Swift then it has to be through an app and "any old app" could do it.  It would probably require non-public APIs though so only sketchier apps that don't care about being banned when they're found out are likely to try through the app store, but Cydia apps on rooted phones would be  a potential issue.

Comment: I'm certainly not looking for a sketchy work around. I'm looking for a publicly usable API for managing the trust store. Apple should have explicit app permissions for access to the trust store.

Comment: You can certainly do cert pinning in your own app. But I assume you mean that you want to do this so that _other_ apps also trust the cert?

Comment: Actually my goal is to _remove_ certificates from the trust store, or at least to distrust/block them. I don't intend to add any cert.

Comment: Interesting. I would be extremely surprised if Apple allowed that.

Comment: I’m sure your intuition is correct. There is surprisingly little discussion of this.